# Powershell Splitting a List

Tags: string, powershell, loops, split, active-directory

I am reading in a file with a lot of information and I need to pick out the First Name and Last Name of each user.

The below code, splits on commas (as I am not interested in anything after a comma) and then splits on spaces. The names will be in the 10th to 12th indexed positions (including double barrelled names). I need the a variable with all the names saved like seen below. They are read in in lines i.e. 'New Starter Joe Smith, 04/10/2022' but my code is splitting them up so Joe and Smith are on separate lines. How do I get the below ideally?

```
$names = $list | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(",")[0] };
$name = $names | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(" ")[10,11,12]+","}
```

Joe Smith

Stephen Mark Davies

Anna Walker

Roger Phillips

Comment: Can you show us a few sample lines from the input file? `'New Starter Joe Smith, 04/10/2022'` is clearly not that, it doesn't have enough spaces :)

Comment: Tell us about a new starter in your team - Joe Smith,04/10/2022 Tell us about a new starter in your team - Stephen Mark Davies,04/10/2022

Comment: It would be in that format

Comment: Then why are you using `10,11,12` as the indices? It would be from index 2 until the end of the array:  `$words = 'New Starter Joe Smith'.Split(' '); $words[2..$($words.Length - 1)]`

Comment: It can be achieved by using split function by two times if your whole list is going to be in the same manner. ```$string = "Tell us about a new starter in your team - Joe Smith,04/10/2022"
$splitLine = $string.Split('-')
$name = $splitLine[1].split(',')
$name[0] ```